DndContext Animation triggers twice
I have implemented dndkit drag end drop kanban board
Im using drag overlay and sortable, when moving the columns the transitions work, but on drag end, its shows already moved, but when i let it go, it animates everything again.
How can i solve this, or what is the problem??
my kabanboard.tsx

  function handleDragEnd(event: DragEndEvent) {
    setActiveColumn(null);
    setActiveTask(null);
    const { active, over } = event;

    if (!over) return;

    // Check if dragging a column or task
    const isColumn = active.data.current?.type === "Column";
    const isTask = active.data.current?.type === "Task";

    if (isColumn && over.data.current?.type === "Column") {
      // Handle column reordering
      const activeColumnId = active.id;
      const overColumnId = over.id;

      if (activeColumnId !== overColumnId) {
        setColumns((columns) => {
          const overIndex = columns.findIndex(
            (column) => column.id === overColumnId,
          );
          const activeIndex = columns.findIndex(
            (column) => column.id === activeColumnId,
          );
          return arrayMove(columns, activeIndex, overIndex);
        });
      }
    } else if (isTask && over.data.current?.type === "Task") {
      // Handle task reordering
      const activeTaskId = active.id;
      const overTaskId = over.id;

      setTasks((tasks) => {
        const activeTaskIndex = tasks.findIndex((t) => t.id === activeTaskId);
        const overTaskIndex = tasks.findIndex((t) => t.id === overTaskId);

        const updatedTasks = [...tasks];
        updatedTasks[activeTaskIndex].columnId = tasks[overTaskIndex].columnId;

        return arrayMove(updatedTasks, activeTaskIndex, overTaskIndex);
      });
    } else if (isTask && over.data.current?.type === "Column") {
      // Handle moving task to a different column
      const activeTaskId = active.id;
      const overColumnId = over.id;

      setTasks((tasks) => {
        const activeTaskIndex = tasks.findIndex((t) => t.id === activeTaskId);
        const updatedTasks = [...tasks];
        updatedTasks[activeTaskIndex].columnId = overColumnId;

        return updatedTasks;
      });
    }
  }

  function handleDragStart(event: DragStartEvent) {
    console.log(event);
    if (event.active.data.current?.type === "Column") {
      setActiveColumn(event.active.data.current.column);
      return;
    }
    if (event.active.data.current?.type === "Task") {
      setActiveTask(event.active.data.current.task);
      return;
    }
  }

  function handleDragOver(event: DragOverEvent) {
    const { active, over } = event;

    console.log("-----------");
    console.log("active", active);
    console.log("over", over);

    if (!over) return;

    const activeId = active.id;
    const overId = over.id;
    if (activeId === overId) return;

    const isActiveTask = active.data.current?.type === "Task";
    const isOverTask = over.data.current?.type === "Task";

    if (isActiveTask && isOverTask) {
      setTasks((tasks) => {
        const activeIndex = tasks.findIndex((t) => t.id === activeId);
        const overIndex = tasks.findIndex((t) => t.id === overId);

        tasks[activeIndex].columnId = tasks[overIndex].columnId;

        return arrayMove(tasks, activeIndex, overIndex);
      });
    }

    const isOverAColumn = over.data.current?.type === "Column";
    if (isActiveTask && isOverAColumn) {
      setTasks((tasks) => {
        const activeIndex = tasks.findIndex((t) => t.id === activeId);

        tasks[activeIndex].columnId = overId;

        return arrayMove(tasks, activeIndex, activeIndex);
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <Flex
      align="flex-start"
      style={{
        overflowX: "auto",
        overflowY: "auto",
      }}
      flex={7.5}
      mih={500}
      px={40}
      pb={"lg"}
    >
      <DndContext
        sensors={sensors}
        collisionDetection={closestCenter}
        onDragStart={handleDragStart}
        onDragOver={handleDragOver}
        onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
      >
        <SortableContext items={columnIds}>
          {columns.map((column, idx) => (
            <KanbanColumn
              key={idx}
              column={column}
              updateColumn={handleUpdateColumn}
              createTask={handleCreateTask}
              tasks={tasks.filter((task) => task.columnId === column.id)}
              updateTask={handleUpdateTask}
              deleteTask={handleDeleteTask}
              deleteColumn={handleDeleteColumn}
            />
          ))}
        </SortableContext>

        <UnstyledButton className={classes.button} onClick={open} p={"xs"}>
          <IconPlus style={{ width: rem(24), height: rem(24) }} />
        </UnstyledButton>
        <CreateColumnModal
          opened={opened}
          close={close}
          handleCreate={handleCreateColumn}
        />
        {createPortal(
          <DragOverlay>
            {activeColumn && (
              <ColumnOverlay
                column={activeColumn}
                tasks={tasks.filter(
                  (task) => task.columnId === activeColumn.id,
                )}
              />
            )}
            {activeTask && <TaskOverlay task={activeTask} />}
          </DragOverlay>,
          document.body,
        )}
      </DndContext>
    </Flex>
  );
}


my kanbanColumn.tsx
import { Column, Id, Task } from "@/types/viewTypes";
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Container,
  Divider,
  Flex,
  rem,
  ScrollArea,
  Stack,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Title,
  UnstyledButton,
} from "@mantine/core";
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import KanbanTask from "./KanbanTask";
import { useDroppable } from "@dnd-kit/core";
import {
  SortableContext,
  useSortable,
  verticalListSortingStrategy,
} from "@dnd-kit/sortable";
import { CSS } from "@dnd-kit/utilities";
import { IconPlus, IconTrash } from "@tabler/icons-react";
import ColumnOptionsButton from "./ColumnOptionsButton";

export default function KanbanColumn({
  column,
  updateColumn,
  createTask,
  tasks,
  updateTask,
  deleteTask,
  deleteColumn,
}: {
  column: Column;
  updateColumn: (title: string, columnId: Id) => void;
  createTask: (columnId: Id) => void;
  tasks: Task[];
  updateTask: (taskId: Id, newContent: string) => void;
  deleteTask: (taskId: Id) => void;
  deleteColumn: (columnId: Id) => void;
}) {
  const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);

  const tasksIds = useMemo(() => {
    return tasks.map((task) => task.id);
  }, [tasks]);

  const {
    attributes,
    listeners,
    setNodeRef,
    transform,
    transition,
    isDragging,
  } = useSortable({
    id: column.id,
    data: {
      type: "Column",
      column,
    },
    disabled: editMode,
    transition: {
      duration: 5500,
      easing: "cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.5, 1)",
    },
  });

  const style = {
    transform: CSS.Translate.toString(transform),
    transition,
  };

  if (isDragging) {
    return (
      <Container
        className="rounded-md"
        ref={setNodeRef}
        style={style}
        mx={"xs"}
        mih={"100%"}
        bg={"gray"}
        miw={300}
        maw={300}
        p={"xs"}
        opacity={"50%"}
      ></Container>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Container
      className="rounded-md"
      ref={setNodeRef}
      style={style}
      mx={"xs"}
      mih={"100%"}
      bg={"backgroundGray"}
      miw={300}
      maw={300}
      p={"xs"}
      bd={"0.5px solid gray"}
    >
      <Stack align={"space-between"} gap={"md"}>
        {editMode ? (
          <TextInput
            p={"xs"}
            value={column.title}
            onChange={(e) => updateColumn(e.target.value, column.id)}
            autoFocus
            onBlur={() => {
              setEditMode(false);
            }}
            onKeyDown={(e) => {
              if (e.key !== "Enter") return;
              setEditMode(false);
            }}
          />
        ) : (
          <Flex justify={"space-between"} align={"center"}>
            <Text
              onClick={() => setEditMode(true)}
              flex={1}
              fw={800}
              c={"dark"}
              size="lg"
              className={"hover:bg-neutral-200 rounded-md"}
              p={"xs"}
              {...attributes}
              {...listeners}
            >
              {column.title}
            </Text>
            <ColumnOptionsButton deleteColumn={deleteColumn} column={column} />
          </Flex>
        )}
        <Divider />
        <SortableContext items={tasksIds}>
          <ScrollArea type="auto">
            {tasks.map((task, idx) => (
              <KanbanTask
                task={task}
                updateTask={updateTask}
                deleteTask={deleteTask}
              />
            ))}
          </ScrollArea>
        </SortableContext>
        <UnstyledButton
          onClick={() => createTask(column.id)}
          p={"xs"}
          c={"dimmed"}
          className="hover:bg-neutral-200 rounded-md "
        >
          <Flex align={"center"} gap={"sm"}>
            <IconPlus
              // color={"--mantine-color-dark-5"}
              style={{ width: rem(16), height: rem(16) }}
            />
            <Text>Add Task</Text>
          </Flex>
        </UnstyledButton>
      </Stack>
    </Container>
  );
}


